# Display Progress Dialog While AdMob Fetches Ad

Tags: android, layout, admob, progressdialog

My app has an activity where the ad is best placed in the center of the screen.  I've made the other elements sit relative to the ad either above or below.  I like the way it looks when the ad is present, but when the activity starts everything is mashed together.

What I would like to do is display a progress dialog in the space where the ad will go if AdMob delivers an ad.

I have implemented my ads in the XML way documented here: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html

Can someone put me on the right path?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.aydabtu.BroadcastSMS"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/megaphone_320x480"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/num_messages"
        android:background="@drawable/semiTransparentLt"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/num_msgs_title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/smsMsgBody_editText"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/semiTransparentLt"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/num_msgs"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/num_msgs_title"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/num_msgs_title"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:lines="5"
        android:minLines="5"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:id="@id/smsMsgBody_editText"
        android:hint="@string/sms_edittext"
        android:layout_above="@+id/body_len"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/semiTransparentLt"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@id/body_len"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingRight="10sp"
        android:text="@string/clear_text"
        android:background="@drawable/semiTransparentLt"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/clear_text"
        android:layout_above="@id/ad"
        />
    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
        android:id="@id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        myapp:backgroundColor="@drawable/black"
        myapp:primaryTextColor="@drawable/white"
        myapp:secondaryTextColor="@drawable/drkGrey"
        android:layout_above="@+id/broadcastMsg_button"     
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/broadcastMsg_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/broadcast_sms_button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say place a frame layout where you have the AdView now.
Place an AdView and circular ProgressBar within the AdView. Might need some tweaking to hide the ProgressBar once the AdView appears, but should be work.

If you post your exact XML. I will give a more detailed explanation.

Comment: The AdMob SDK implements a listener so one can determine if an ad has been or will not be loaded.  You're suggesting implementing a FrameView in place of the AdView (above) and have 2 elements that overlap.  That seems like the right idea.  With the AdListener() I can turn those elements on/off easy enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I'm suggesting.